# Why touch image zooming doesnt work

Tags: android

In my project im showing an image in an activity.When i touch the image with two fingers, i will hide the view containing that imageview.Then in to the frame layout i will add a custom touchmimage view so that i can zoom that image.But something went wrong somewhere.Im sharing my code here

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.touchfinger"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/closeicon"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:longClickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String TAG = "Multitouch";
    int modeW;
    ImageView im, close;

    TouchImageView zImg;
    LinearLayout linearlayout;
    FrameLayout frame;
    Bitmap bmp;

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    float currentX;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        close = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.close);
        linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        zImg = new TouchImageView(this);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext()
                .getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
        if (bmp == null) {
            Log.e("Bitmap is null", "Bitmap is null");
        } else {

            Log.e("Bitmap is not null", "Bitmap is not null");
        }

        im.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 final float X = event.getX();

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    modeW = 1;

                    try {
                        close.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linearlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        frame.addView(zImg);
                        zImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        zImg.setMaxZoom(3f);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    modeW = 0;
                    currentX = X;

                    zImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (modeW == 0)

                        break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float currentx = event.getX();
                    float diff = currentX - currentx;
                    if (diff > 9.0 || diff < -9.0)
                        modeW = 2;
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }

        });
        close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                close.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                frame.removeAllViews();

                linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Touchimageview

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

    float width, height;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;


    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                            float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                            if (scaleWidth < width) {
                                deltaX = 0;
                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                            } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                                deltaY = 0;
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);
                            } else {
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);

                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);

                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) { 
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        if(bm!=null)
        {
            bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
            bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
        }
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x)
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = (float)Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
                 matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    matrix.getValues(m);
                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        } else {
                            if (x < -right) 
                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0) 
                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (x < -right) 
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0) 
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
           return true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX =  (float)width / (float)bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float)height / (float)bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = (float)height - (scale * (float)bmHeight) ;
        redundantXSpace = (float)width - (scale * (float)bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

And pressing the close button i will go back to the previous stage.But zooming doesnt work here.Can some one say what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
TouchImageView.java

package com.your.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Extends Android ImageView to include pinch zooming and panning.
 */
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

    float width, height;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context)
    {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG)
                        {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                            float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                            if (scaleWidth < width)
                            {
                                deltaX = 0;
                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            else if (scaleHeight < height)
                            {
                                deltaY = 0;
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                    deltaX = -x;
                                else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                    deltaX = -(x + right);

                                if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                    deltaY = -y;
                                else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                    deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                            }
                            matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
    {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        if (bm != null)
        {
            bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
            bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
        }
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x)
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
        {
            float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(
                    Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale)
            {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            }
            else if (saveScale < minScale)
            {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
            bottom = height * saveScale - height
                    - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height)
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    matrix.getValues(m);
                    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                    {
                        if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width)
                        {
                            if (y < -bottom)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                            else if (y > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (x < -right)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                            else if (x > 0)
                                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(),
                        detector.getFocusY());
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1)
                {
                    if (x < -right)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;
        float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        saveScale = 1f;

        // Center the image
        redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

touch_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imageViewGallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    class="com.your.package.TouchImageView" />
```

in Activity:

```
    TouchImageView imageViewGallery = (TouchImageView) inflate(c,
            R.touch_layout, null);

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/Folder/Images/file.png", o2);

    imageViewGallery.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageViewGallery.setMaxZoom(4f);
```

Comment: I think im already using this code.Problem isnt with touchimageview.Its working in normal case,But im not able to zoom in the above case